# How to remove added classes from an element in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a drag n drop sort of game where you match the logos with their corresponding name.

If user matches the logo with the name correctly than the field which you could drop the logo gets additional classes.

Like this:

```
if (isCorrectMatching) {
  event.target.classList.add("dropped");
  draggableElement.classList.add("dragged");
  event.target.classList.add("dragged");
  event.target.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
  draggableElement.setAttribute("draggable", "false");
  event.target.innerHTML = `<i class="fab fa-${draggableElementBrand}" style="color: ${draggableElement.style.color};"></i>`;
}
```

If every match is found user can go to next level ,  my problem is that these additional classes are staying there , how do I remove them ?

I am  mapping them out  like this:

```
<div className="containerItems">
  {draggableItems.map((x, i) => {
    return (
      <div className="draggable-items">
        <i
          onDragStart={(e) => dragStart(e)}
          className={`draggable fab fa-${x}`}
          id={x}
          draggable="true"
          ref={draggableOnes.current[i]}
        ></i>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>;

{
  matchingPairs.map((x, i) => {
    return (
      <section className="matching-pairs">
        <div className="matching-pair">
          <span className="label">{x}</span>
          <span
            className="droppable"
            // ref={droppableOnes.current[i]}
            onDragEnter={(e) => dragEnter(e)}
            onDragOver={(e) => dragOver(e)}
            onDragLeave={(e) => dragLeave(e)}
            onDrop={(e) => drop(e)}
            data-brand={x}
          ></span>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  });
}
```

I can not seem to solve this one, like how do I remove all the classes that I've added when there was a correct matching.

I would like to remove basically everything that I've added in my if (isCorrectMatching) .

I've tried to use refs but it did not work. What is the way to go for this?

Answer (score 1):

In React, you don't directly manipulate DOM elements (well, almost never), including their the class lists. Instead, you keep your state information in the component and use that state information to render the elements that make up your component (including their classes). React will then compare the rendered elements you return with the DOM and make any necessary changes (such as updating the `classList`). So in your code, when you see that you have a correct matching, you **wouldn't** directly modify those DOM elements' `classList` lists, you'd update your state to remember the match, and use that state information in the next render to put the appropriate classes on the elements being rendered.

Here's a simpler example with a tickbox, but it's the same general concept:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    return <div>
        <label>
            <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                onChange={() => setIsChecked(flag => !flag)}
            />
            Ticked
        </label>
        <div className={isChecked ? "yes" : "no"}>
            Example
        </div>
    </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.yes {
    color: green;
}
.no {
    color: #d00;
}
label {
    user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Note how the state member `isChecked` determines what classes the `div` has, and is updated by ticking/unticking the checkbox.

Comment: thanks for the response, yes I could have made the class lists in react way, I am going to do the way you suggested, but how do I make up for the icon that I am adding to the drop field (last line in my if statement)

Comment: @Mynameisjeff - You'd use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) for that. :-)